# Probability of finding a job

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A candidate is selected for interview for 3 posts.The number of candidates for the first, second and third posts are 3,4 and 2 respectively. What is the probability of getting at least one post?

My Solution:

```
P(Candidate gets first job) = 1/3
P(Candidate gets second job) = 1/4
P(Candidate gets 3rd job) = 1/2

P(Candidate gets at least one job) = 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/2 
                                   = (4 + 3 + 6)/12
```

This gives me a probability greater than 1. What seems to be wrong with my method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability the candidate **does not** get an offer from the first interview is $\frac{2}{3}$. The probability she doesn't get an offer from the second is $\frac{3}{4}$, and the probability she doesn't get an offer from the third is $\frac{1}{2}$.

So the probability she does not get an offer at all is $\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$. Here we are assuming (unrealistically) **independence**.

Thus the probability she gets at least one offer is $\frac{3}{4}$.

The thing that is wrong about your method is that you are double-counting the cases where she gets $2$ offers, and triple-counting the cases where she gets $3$ offers. That is why your sum is greater than the correct value. Luckily, it turned out to be grater than $1$, which makes it clear that something is not right.

Later, you will learn how to get rid of such multiple counting by using the Method of Inclusion/Exclusion. However, I am guessing you are not yet at that point in the course, so took the simpler approach above.

**Remark:** We made the totally unreasonable assumption that job offers are given at random, that if there are $3$ people interviewed, exactly one, chosen at random, will get an offer. That's not quite the way the world works!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response :)

Comment: You are welcome. Detail is necessary if you are to follow the logic of the argument, and solve problems of a similar character on your own. It is a very good thing that on getting a number $\gt 1$ you saw that there was something wrong. Surprisingly many people would write down $\frac{13}{12}$ as the answer, and go on to the next question!

Comment: Can you recommend any good resources on Probability?

Comment: I do not know what is good on the Internet. Khan Academy seems OK. There are many good standard books, like the one by Ross. Depends how much background you have. For Ross, absolutely need calculus.

Answer (score 0):

you need to figure out the P(A or B or C) which is P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A and B and C) - P(A and B) - P(A and C) - P(B and C)

so would be 1/4 + 1/2 + 1/3 - [(1/4)(1/2)(1/3)] - [(1/4)(1/2)] - [(1/4)(1/3)] - [(1/2)(1/3)]

which is

13/2 - 1/24 - 1/8 - 1/12 - 1/6

which comes to 3/4 just like the original poster said, but without showing the complicated math.  The way they did it was a lot easier to figure out, because you CAN get 0 jobs, but you won't be able to get all 3 jobs.  So using the multiplication rule of probabilities to figure out the P of getting 0 jobs and subtracting that from 1 gives you the probability of getting at least one job, which is all we care about.